# Как отправить сообщение конкретному пользователю Ratchet?

Tags: php, laravel, ratchet

Я разрабатываю чат платформу.
В качестве серверной части использую Laravel + библиотеку Ratchet для работы с сокетами.

Когда пользователь октрывает чат, устанавливается соединение по сокетам. Однако, когда собеседник пишет сообщение в чат, то оно отправляется всем остальным, а не конкретному второму собеседнику в чате. (ВАЖНО: чат только 1 на 1)

Я перечитал много туториалов и посмотрел большое количество примеров, однако я все также не понимаю, как мне отправить сообщение конкретному пользователю?
Я сохранию id подключения в отдельном массиве users, но как оттуда выбрать нужного мне пользователя - не могу понять.

Стоит отметить, что в базу данных сообщения приходят правильно, они закреплены за нужными чат комнатами.
Вот мод класс чата:

```
class ChatSocket extends BaseSocket
{
    protected $clients;
    protected $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
        $this->users = [];
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        $this->users[$conn->resourceId] = $conn;

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;

        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        $data = json_decode($msg, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

//        Save to Database
        $message = new MessageController();
        $responseData = $message->store($data);

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client === $from) {
                $client->send(json_encode($responseData, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
            }
        }
    }



    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
```

Вот код клиента (очень топорный, в качестве id я отправляю айдишники пользователей (берется из БД).

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            let data = {
                sender_id: 1,
                to: 2,
                chat_room_id: 1,
                message: this.message.value
            };

            socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

        })

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            console.log(data);
}
```

Я понимаю, что мне нужно что-то вроде такого, однако как получить этот самый $to - не понимаю.

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $to, $msg) {
foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
  if ($to== $client) {  
    $client->send();
       }
}
}
```

Comment: Получаете от клиента сообщение определённого формата, типа `register Vasya`. Так вы свяжете клиента веб-сокета с пользователем Вася. Когда нужно будет отправить сообщение Ивану, то Вася отправить сообщение на сервер `send to Ivan text "best friends"`. Так как все пользователи зарегистрировались, то вам не составит из списка клиентов выбрать нужного

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с использованием БД. Вот код, может кому пригодится

```
class ChatSocket extends BaseSocket
{
    protected $clients;
    protected $message;
    protected $audioClients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
        $this->message = new MessageController();
        $this->audioClients = [];
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $responseData = [];
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv === 1 ? '' : 's');

        $data = json_decode($msg, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

        if ($data['type'] === 'subscribe') {
            $this->updateSocketId($data['sender_id'], $from->resourceId);
        } elseif ($data['type'] === 'message') {
            $receiverIds = $this->getSocketIdByChatRoom($data['sender_id'], $data['receiverId']);
            $message = $this->message->store($data);

            $responseData = [
                "sender_id" => $message->sender_id,
                "message" => $message->message,
                "audio" => $message->audio,
                "chat_room_id" => $message->chat_room_id,
                "created_at" => date('H:i', strtotime($message->created_at))
            ];

            foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                foreach ($receiverIds as $receiver) {
                    if ($client->resourceId === $receiver->socket_id) {
                        $client->send(json_encode($responseData, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
                    }
                }
            }
        } elseif ($data['type'] === 'call') {
            $receiverId = DB::table('users')->select('socket_id')->
                where('id', [$data['receiverId']])->value('socket_id');
            $responseData = [
                'type' => $data['type'],
                'sender_id' => $data['sender_id'],
                'receiverId' => $data['receiverId'],
                'voice_audio' => $data['voice_audio']
            ];
            foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                if ($client->resourceId === $receiverId) {
                    dump('Sending...');
                    $client->send(json_encode($responseData, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }

    public function updateSocketId($userId,$socketId): int
    {
        return DB::table('users')->where('id', $userId)->update(['socket_id' => $socketId]);
    }

    public function getSocketIdByChatRoom($senderId, $receiverId): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        return Db::table('users')->select('socket_id')->whereIn('id', [$senderId, $receiverId])->get();
    }
}
```